# Making Spark functions accessible from within a bespoke function in mutate

Tags: r, function, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

While working with Spark RDD via [sparklyr](/questions/tagged/sparklyr), I would like to wrap some of the common transformations to pass them more convientntly to `mutate` syntax.

## Example

For instance, while working with a data with the following timestamps:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00.0
2000-02-02 00:00:00.0
```

I can convert those to a more useful **`YYYY-MM-dd`** format using the syntax:

```
mutate(nice_date= from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(bad_timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-dd'))
```

## Challenge

As I do it frequently, I would like to wrap the `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(bad_timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-dd'))` call and use syntax:

```
mutate(nice_date = from_unix_to_nice(bad_date))
```

Conventional approach would suggest writing a function:

```
from_unix_to_nice<- function(x) {
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(x), 'YYYY-MM-dd')
}
```

### Problem

When applied the function fails:

```
> Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function
> from_unix_to_nice; line 2 pos 62  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2$$anonfun$1.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:69)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2$$anonfun$1.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:69)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
```

*How can I conveniently develop wrappers for common mutate operations so I can pass those to sparklyr pipeline?*

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful (I don't know sparklyr nor Spark very much, so it could be out of topic, if so, sorry) https://spark.rstudio.com/extensions.html#wrapper_functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is that the function needs to be passed un-evaluated to the `mutate()` function.  The `rlang` package can be done to accomplish this, here is an example:

```
library(rlang)
library(sparklyr) 
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

just_time <- flights %>%
     select(time_hour) %>%
     mutate(time_hour = as.character(time_hour))
     head(100)

spark_flights <- copy_to(sc, just_time, "flights")


from_unix_to_nice<- function(x) {
  x <- enexpr(x)
  expr(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(!!x), 'YYYY-MM-dd'))
}

from_unix_to_nice(test)


spark_flights %>%
  mutate(new_field =  !!from_unix_to_nice(time_hour))
```

The `from_unix_to_nice()` function now passes: `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(test), "YYYY-MM-dd")` to `mutate()` as if you would have typed that exact syntax.